# Sort multi column Listbox by date (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: vba, date, sorting, listbox

I have a multi column listbox that is populated using the following code:

```
Plybooks.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 5
Plybooks.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "200;200;150;100;60"

If Plybooks.OptionButton12.Value = True Then
    For Idx = 0 To 9
        For Each MyCell In AllAreas(Idx).Cells
            If InStr(1, MyCell.Value, "(FS)") > 0 Then
                Plybooks.ListBox1.AddItem
                Plybooks.ListBox1.List(I, 0) = MyCell.Offset(, -1).Value
                Plybooks.ListBox1.List(I, 1) = MyCell.Value
                Plybooks.ListBox1.List(I, 2) = MyCell.Offset(, 2).Value
                Plybooks.ListBox1.List(I, 3) = MyCell.Offset(, 3).Value
                Plybooks.ListBox1.List(I, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray)
                Plybooks.ListBox1.List(I, 4) = MyCell.Offset(, 4).Value
                I = I + 1
            End If
        Next MyCell
    Next Idx
```

I use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray)` to format the 5th column to date: dd/mm/yyyy. This works well but the issue comes when I try to sort my Listbox data by this date. I am using a bubble sort, as shown below. This works in as much as it sorts the days correctly, but does not take in to account months or years. As such data is sorted as:

05/10/2020

06/11/2020

07/11/2020

08/10/2020

09/09/2020

```
    Dim j As Long
    Dim temp1 As Variant
    Dim temp2 As Variant
    Dim temp3 As Variant
    Dim temp4 As Variant
    Dim temp0 As Variant
    With Plybooks.ListBox1
        For j = LBound(.List) To UBound(.List) - 1
            For I = j To UBound(.List) - 1
                If .List(I, 4) < .List(j, 4) Then
                    temp1 = .List(I, 1)
                    .List(I, 1) = .List(j, 1)
                    .List(j, 1) = temp1
                    temp2 = .List(I, 2)
                    .List(I, 2) = .List(j, 2)
                    .List(j, 2) = temp2
                    temp3 = .List(I, 3)
                    .List(I, 3) = .List(j, 3)
                    .List(j, 3) = temp3
                    temp4 = .List(I, 4)
                    .List(I, 4) = .List(j, 4)
                    .List(j, 4) = temp4
                    temp0 = .List(I, 0)
                    .List(I, 0) = .List(j, 0)
                    .List(j, 0) = temp0
                End If
            Next I
        Next j
    End With
```

I need a solution that sorts to the date correctly, with the closest date at the top of the Listbox.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to comparing the two dates, you'll need to convert them into true date values.  Also, your `For/Next` loops don't seem to be set up quite right.  Try the following...

```
Dim date1 As Variant
Dim date2 As Variant
Dim temp As Variant
Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

With Plybooks.ListBox1
    For i = LBound(.List) To UBound(.List) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(.List)
            date1 = .List(i, 4)
            If IsDate(date1) Then
                arr = Split(date1, "/")
                date1 = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
            End If
            date2 = .List(j, 4)
            If IsDate(date2) Then
                arr = Split(date2, "/")
                date2 = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(1), arr(0))
            End If
            If date1 < date2 Then
                For k = 0 to 4
                    temp = .List(i, k)
                    .List(i, k) = .List(j, k)
                    .List(j, k) = temp
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there are some issues here. Firstly I get an error on type mismatch if not all the data in the date column is a date. For my data this is the case sometimes, so I guess I need an IF statement to check that data is date format before sorting. But for the purpose of testing this code I fudged the data to remove the non-dates and still got a "Could not set the List property. Type mismatch" error on `.List(i, k) = .List(j, k)`. The last issue is that this seems to put my data into mm/dd/yyyy format where the source data is actually dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: I have amended the code so that it first checks whether a value can be converted to a date.  If so, it converts the value to a date.  Otherwise, the value remains unchanged.  Then the values are compared for sorting.

Comment: It still doesn't like `.List(i, k) = .List(j, k)`, I am getting "Could not set the List property. Type mismatch"

Comment: When you click on Debug and it highlights that line, move your cursor over each List property.  What values are displayed for each one?

Comment: It's probably because your source data contains error values, and then in the sort procedure it's trying to assign an error value to a list item during the swap.  If this is the case, I would suggest that you ensure  that all error values in your source data is replaced with an appropriate text value.  For example, the error value #N/A could be replaced with the string value "#N/A", the error value #DIV/0! could be replaced with an blank/empty string ( "" ), and so on.

Comment: Each list property = Null

Comment: .List(i,k) = Null, i = 0, k = 5, .List(j,k) = Null, j = 3, k = 5

Comment: would the IF statement `If IsDate(date1) Then` not already ignore any data containing error values? Or do errors need to be replaced with string value before that? I have checked all the source data and they are all true date values for the purpose of this test.

Comment: Yes, `IsDate` ignores error values, but you'll still get an error when the values are being compared with `If date1 < date2 Then`.

Comment: And yes, I would suggest that you replace error values with the appropriate string values.

Comment: So it is clear to me that I just don't get this code! I see that you are splitting the date in to 3 strings, namely `arr(1), arr(2)` & `arr(3)`. And I can see that these make up the Variants `date1, date2, temp`. But I don't understand how the code swaps the dates to sort, given that the sort is looking at `.List(i,k)`, not the strings of `arr`. I have also checked no errors in the source data and so I don't think this is what is causing the runtime error

Comment: `arr` is only being used to split the date string into an array.  Then the contents of the array is re-arranged to assign `date1` and `date2` true date values.

Comment: I see now that your source data cannot contain error values.  Otherwise an error would have occurred when trying to assign it to your listbox in your original code.

Comment: In taking a closer look at your original code, I see that you first assign the result of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray)` to a list item, and then you re-assign another value to that same list item.  What is `MyArray`, and why are you re-assigning?

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyArray)` was used to change date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy. Source data has always been in dd/mm/yyyy format but when it arrives in the Listbox it had been changed to mm/dd/yyyy. I did not understand how this code worked - found it on here, but it did seem to. However that is no longer the case and so I've removed that line

Comment: When you add your first item to your listbox using the AddItem method, you're creating a listbox that contains 10 columns.  And so any index for which you have not assigned a value will contain the Null value, hence the error.  So a quick fix would be to change `For k = LBound(.List, 2) To UBound(.List, 2)` to `For k = 0 to 4`.  However, instead of using the AddItem method, I would suggest first filling an array with the worksheet values, making sure the dates are formatted as desired, then sort the array, and then assign the array to your listbox like this `Plybooks.ListBox1.List = MyArray`.